# how to traverse an adjacency list

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, traversal, adjacency-list

This is the struct of adjList

```
typedef struct _node
{
    int weight;
    int label;
    struct _node *next;
} EdgeNode;
typedef struct _vnode
{
    int id;
    EdgeNode *firstedge;
} VertexNode;
typedef VertexNode AdjList[MAX];
```

The graph is loop-free, and the input is a node whose in-degree is zero.
How to traverse(output) all paths of this graph?

for example, the adjList is
1->2->3
2->4
3->4
the output is
path_1: 1->2->4
path_2: 1->3->4

Comment: thank you, it's a great help

Comment: `1->3->4` --> `1->2->3->4`